# Arranging the output of a foreach alphabetically

Tags: php

How do you alphabetically order the output of a foreach loop in a table:

```
<table class="list <?php echo $list_class; ?>">
<tr class="table-header">

<?php
if (is_array($columns)):
    foreach ($columns as $column):
        $column = parse_class($column);
?>
        <th class="<?php echo $column['class']; ?>"><?php echo $column['column']; ?></th>
<?php
    endforeach;
endif;

if (is_array($actions)):
    foreach ($actions as $action): ?>
    <th class="action"></th>
<?php
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
</tr>


<?php
if (is_array($data['page'])):
    foreach ($data['page'] as $item):
        foreach($item as $item_member):
            if(stripos($item_member, $_POST['term']) !== FALSE):
?>
                <tr>
<?php
                foreach ($columns as $key => $column):
                    $key = parse_class($key);
?>
                    <td class="<?php echo $key['class']; ?>"><a class="cell-link" href="<?php echo $details_link . $item[$details_id_field]; ?>">
<?php
                    echo (!empty($item[$key['column']])) ? $item[$key['column']] : '&nbsp;';
?>
                    </a></td>
<?php
                endforeach;
?>
                </tr>

<?php
            endif;
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
</table>
```

I am trying to ensure that the first column is ordered alphabetically.
Can I apply something to the first loop? thanks

Comment: The opening and closing of php tags is massively overused in your script. It is almost impossible to determine where one section ends and another beings.

Comment: Does the data come from a DB?  If so, sort there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the PHP sort function:

```
sort ( $columns );
```

Learn more here: http://php.net/sort